# libcurl function was given a bad argument CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST no longer supports 1 as value

Tags: r, libcurl

While running the "PrepareAnnotationRefseq"  function from the customProDB package in R, I  ran into  a problem due to a compatibility issue of the curl version. I am currently using curl version 4.3.2.  The error report I got is:

```
PrepareAnnotationRefseq(genome='mm39',CDSfasta="geneseq.fasta",pepfasta="proteinseq.fasta", annotation_path, dbsnp = NULL, splice_matrix=FALSE, ClinVar=FALSE)

In curlSetOpt(..., .opts = .opts, curl = h, .encoding = .encoding) : Error setting the option for # 3 (status = 43) (enum = 81) (value = 0x55822c7f3b70): A libcurl function was given a bad argument CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST no longer supports 1 as value!
```

This could be a trivial problem for an expert in R, however with my current skill set I am unable to resolve this after looking for a solution on several forums and R groups. I would be very grateful if you could kindly shed some light on this issue. Perhaps a patch file that can fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to read the manual. Why can't you do it?

> If *verify* value is set to 1:
>
> From 7.28.1 to 7.65.3: setting it to 1 made `curl_easy_setopt()` return an error and leaving the flag untouched.

Use 2.

> When `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` is 2, that certificate must indicate that the server is the server to which you meant to connect, or the connection fails. Simply put, it means it has to have the same name in the certificate as is in the URL you operate against.

But why do you touch it? The default value for this option is 2 and is suitable for most cases of libcurl usage.